Unique submit btn for each user - django
I have a Like button for my posts which users can like the posts or not, which means if a user clicked on the button for the first time the post will be liked by the user and for the second time it will be unliked by the user.
just like Facebook or twitter and etc. I tried a lot to do this but my problem is " when user click on the button it will add one like on the counter and if a user likes again it will count 2 likes for the post by a user!
Anyway, how we can make the likes unique? Each user should be able to like any post just once and if they clicked again it means they unliked a post.
if request.POST.get("single_tweet_like_submit_btn"):
        try:
            # Debug: Check the request and user
            print(f"Request by user: {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} for tweet ID: {current_tweet.id}")

            # Check if the user has already liked the tweet
            tweet_like = TweetLike.objects.filter(tweet=current_tweet, liker=current_basic_user_profile)
            
            if tweet_like:
                # Debug: User has already liked the tweet, so we'll unlike it
                print(f"User {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} has already liked tweet {current_tweet.id}, unliking it.")
                
                # If the user has already liked the tweet, unlike it
                tweet_like.delete()
                
                # Decrement the like count
                current_tweet.tweet_like_amount = max(0, current_tweet.tweet_like_amount - 1)
            else:
                # Debug: User has not liked the tweet yet, so we'll like it
                print(f"User {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} has not liked tweet {current_tweet.id}, liking it.")

                # If the user hasn't liked the tweet, like it
                new_like = TweetLike(tweet=current_tweet, liker=current_basic_user_profile)
                new_like.save()
                
                # Increment the like count
                current_tweet.tweet_like_amount += 1
                
                # Create a notification for the like
                new_notification = NotificationLike(
                    notified=current_tweet.user,
                    notifier=current_basic_user_profile,
                    tweet=current_tweet,
                )
                new_notification.save()
            
            # Save the current tweet's state
            current_tweet.save()

            # Debug: Output the new like count
            print(f"Tweet {current_tweet.id} now has {current_tweet.tweet_like_amount} likes.")
            
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions appropriately
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")  # For debugging purposes
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/tweet/{current_tweet.id}/")

I tried a lot of ways to fix the problem but no success :)
Update:
models.py
# Tweet Like
# --------------
class TweetLike(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(
        Tweet,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    liker = models.ForeignKey(
        BasicUserProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        unique = True
    )
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('tweet', 'liker')


    def __str__(self):
        return "Like id: " + str(self.id)

authentication/models.py
class BasicUserProfile(models.Model):
# One-to-one relationship with Django's User model
user = models.OneToOneField(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
creation_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

# Profile settings
profile_photo = models.ImageField(
    upload_to="profile_photo/", blank=True, null=True
)
banner_photo = models.ImageField(
    upload_to="banner_photo/", blank=True, null=True
)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"User: {self.user.username}"


Please add your TweetLike and your basic_user_profile class.

@raphael Sure! I updated the post.

There might be a way to do what you want given your models, but I believe a better approach would be to eliminate the TweetLike class altogether.  Instead add a ManyToManyField field in your Tweet class with BasicUserProfile.  When a user clicks the like button, add the user, when the user clicks it again, remove them from the ManyToManyField.  To get the total likes you can simply count all the users in the ManyToManyField.  Take a look here.

You approach is almost corrent, ensure that a user can only like or unlike a post once, you need to check if the like already exists and then either delete it or add it, adjusting the like count accordingly.
if request.POST.get("single_tweet_like_submit_btn"):
    try:
        print(f"Request by user: {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} for tweet ID: {current_tweet.id}")

        # Toggle like status
        tweet_like, created = TweetLike.objects.get_or_create(tweet=current_tweet, liker=current_basic_user_profile)
        
        if created:
            print(f"User {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} liked tweet {current_tweet.id}.")
            current_tweet.tweet_like_amount += 1
            NotificationLike.objects.create(
                notified=current_tweet.user,
                notifier=current_basic_user_profile,
                tweet=current_tweet,
            )
        else:
            print(f"User {current_basic_user_profile.user.username} unliked tweet {current_tweet.id}.")
            tweet_like.delete()
            current_tweet.tweet_like_amount = max(0, current_tweet.tweet_like_amount - 1)
        
        current_tweet.save()
        print(f"Tweet {current_tweet.id} now has {current_tweet.tweet_like_amount} likes.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/tweet/{current_tweet.id}/")

my code uses get_or_create to simplify the process of checking if the like already exists and changesthe like status accordingly.

The problem of your code is when someone wants to like the post, it should click on the button twice and that is because the code goes to check first and then like it or dislike it :(

An error occurred: get() returned more than one TweetLike -- it returned 2!
[18/Jun/2024 20:55:54] "POST /tweet/138/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31015

check if the like already exists with filter().exists(), then delete it and decrement the like count if it exists, or create it and increment the like count with a notification if it doesn't, save the tweet, and redirect the user to the tweet page.
